# adjust iframe height based on number of record in gridview

Tags: css, asp.net, iframe, gridview, dialog

I have a jquery dialog box that contains iframe.

The iframe contains the asp.net gridview. It can be 0, 1, or many.

If it is 1, the iframe should be resize to the height of one record. if there are two, resize to two, and so on. Of course, there is a limitation. Currently,I want to display 10 records without scroll bar. if there are 10 records, scroll bar. For the starter, I am assuming, each record occupies one line (it can occupy more than one line, but right now, I just want to make it work for a simple case) 
There are various resources to resolve this issue. Many people have suggested min-height

http://forums.asp.net/t/1923309.aspx?+div+height+abject+dynamically+based+on+Gridview+

However, I tried that method, and it does not work

My understanding is if there is only one record, the height will be adjust to 19px, and the height will be adjust based on the gridview. If there are more than 10 records, the height will be 190px and scroll bar is show.

I do not get the result I want. The height is always 150px even if there is only one record

[image: iframe with only one record, but it does not resize]

As you can tell the height does not shrink to 19px.

Anything else I need to do

Also, Some people have suggested resize the iframe dynamically. I want to avoid that one. If I can accomplish in simple CSS, it will be great. Of course, I don't rule out javascript if there is no alternative. However, many people mentioned that min-height should solve the problem. There could be a lot more coding and debugging if use the javascript to resize

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.

There are some CSS workarounds floating around the web, like [this](http://www.bymichaellancaster.com/blog/fluid-iframe-and-images-without-javascript-plugins/) and [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?46273-I-Made-a-Fluid-IFrame!), however these '*solutions*' are for specific cases.
The best way to do this would be through JS, like people have suggested to you. Code is not big, debugging would not take a long time (if any).

Just declare a function:

```
function resize(frame) {
    frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

And add `onLoad` event to your iframe like so:

```
<iframe id="frame1" onLoad="resize(this);"></iframe>
```

What this does: when iframe is loaded with content, the frame's height is set to loaded content body height.